# React TypeError this._test is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax-error, ecmascript-6

Since im new to JavaScript and React, i really have problems figuring out the right syntax.

Here my problem:

`_handleDrop(files)` should call the function `_validateXML(txt)` but doesn't. I receive this error `Uncaught TypeError: this._validateXML is not a function` and can't figure out why.
The callBack `_handleDrop(files)` works fine.

When i try this kind of syntax `_validateXML:function(txt)` i immediately get a error while compiling. Is that because of ecmascript?

```
import React from 'react';
import './UploadXML.scss';
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone';
import xml2js from 'xml2js';

export default class UploadXML extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this._validateXML = this._validateXML.bind(this);
  }

  _validateXML(txt) {
    console.log('Received files: ', txt);
  }

  _handleDrop(files) {
    if (files.length !== 1) {
      throw new Error("Please upload a single file");
    }
    var file = files[0];

    console.log('Received files: ', file);

    this._validateXML(file);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
            <Dropzone onDrop={this._handleDrop} multiple={false}>
              <div>Try dropping some files here, or click to select files to upload.</div>
            </Dropzone>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you're using the ES6 classes instead of React.createClass, it does not autobind **this**.

The reason why:

> React.createClass has a built-in magic feature that bound all methods
>   to this automatically for you. This can be a little confusing for
>   JavaScript developers that are not used to this feature in other
>   classes, or it can be confusing when they move from React to other
>   classes.
>
> Therefore we decided not to have this built-in into React's class
>   model. You can still explicitly prebind methods in your constructor if
>   you want.

Also see: http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding

What you could do in this instance is binding this to your _handleDrop function, like:

```
<Dropzone onDrop={this._handleDrop.bind(this)} multiple={false}>
```

You can also remove the assigning of the function from your constructor.

Comment: This solved my issue with a form within the `onSubmit` portion. I was calling another method within the called method, but it couldn't.

Answer (score 2):

Also, this error can also occur (not in the context of question aske), when Some One passes a function down to a Child Component with wrong name, i.e., the function accessed in the Child Component is not defined due to spelling mistake.

I came here to figure that, but found out that was the case with me. :)
Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

The way we solved this issue is to use an experimental es7 feature which lets you declare a function in this way within a class:

```
handleExpandCollapse = () => {
    this.setState({
      isExpanded: !this.state.isExpanded,
    });
  }
```

And that is autobound to this, so your *JSX* will be the same.